# Any way to style text contained in DataAnnotation Attribute [Display(Name = "Text")]?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I want to do something like this:

```
[Display(Name = "Plain text. <span class=\"red strong\">Red text bolded.</span>")]
```

Is this possible (to style the text within the Display Attribute)? Currently it is just displaying the literal text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible (to style the text within the Display Attribute)?

The problem doesn't lie within the `[Display]` attribute. It lies within the `Html.LabelFor` helper which you used to display. This attribute always HTML encodes the value. If you don't like this behavior you could write a custom helper that will not encode the value:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyLabelFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
    )
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TProperty>(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var labelText = (metadata.DisplayName ?? (metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split(new char[] { '.' }).Last<string>()));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(labelText))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }
        var label = new TagBuilder("label");
        label.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName)));
        label.InnerHtml = labelText;
        return new HtmlString(label.ToString());

    }
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.MyLabelFor(x => x.Foo)
```

Comment: This worked great. Thanks. But now I've run into another problem and opened up a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824252/trying-to-modify-a-builder-to-style-text-in-dataannotation-attribute-displayna

Comment: Would I have to do the same for EditorFor or DisplayFor (that is, a custom helper)? And if so, could I just copy the above code you provided and call it MyEditorFor? Thanks.

Comment: I think that for EditorFor/DisplayFor helpers you could override the [default templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) with custom ones that will call the `MyLabelFor` helper.

Comment: I thought to do that but got a `type argument for methods...cannot be inferred from the usage` error.