# Trying to modify a builder to style text in DataAnnotation Attribute [Display(Name="Text")]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I asked a question and got a great answer for my specific problem, but have run into a problem with `<select>` lists using `<label>` and trying to style the DataAnnotation Attribute `[Display(Name="Text")]` with something like `[Display(Name="Text <span class=\"myclass\">Special styled text</span>.")]`.

Here is the [Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809223/any-way-to-style-text-contained-in-dataannotation-attribute-displayname-tex/9818056#9818056) link.

The answer explained about Html Encoding and presented me with a solution for the `Html.LabelFor` helper. It worked perfectly for my immediate situation. However, I later discovered that since I am using code to create `<select>` lists, the new helper is not being picked up by it.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the `<select>` builder code I am using:

```
public MvcHtmlString BuildInput(string fieldName, 
    SelectListItem item, string inputType)
{
    var id = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(item.Value);
    var wrapper = new TagBuilder("div");
    wrapper.AddCssClass("selector-item");

    var input = new TagBuilder("input");
    input.MergeAttribute("type", inputType);
    input.MergeAttribute("name", fieldName);
    input.MergeAttribute("value", item.Value);
    input.MergeAttribute("id", id);

    input.MergeAttributes(Html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes
        (fieldName, ViewData.ModelMetadata));

    if(item.Selected)
        input.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked");

    wrapper.InnerHtml += input.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);


    var label = new TagBuilder("label"); // tried merging code around 
                                         // here but got it all wrong
    label.MergeAttribute("for", id);
    label.SetInnerText(item.Text);
    wrapper.InnerHtml += label;

    return new MvcHtmlString(wrapper.ToString());
}
```

As I indicated in the code I played around with trying to merge the helper code but could not get it right.

Again, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace:

```
label.SetInnerText(item.Text);
```

with:

```
label.InnerHtml = item.Text;
```